# Mac Eclipse error "Incompatible JVM"

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jvm, jenv

OS X Mavericks. I installed the 64-bit latest eclipse few weeks ago. It ran just fine. A few weeks later, I installed jenv and, I believe, since then eclipse isn't working fine. To be sure, both eclipse and JDK 8 are 64-bit. Why do I get the error dialog "Incompatible JVM" with message as "Version 1.6.x of  the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version 1.7.0 or greater is required".

After locating the eclipse.ini, I find this in the eclipse.ini file.

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
```

Why did eclipse work earlier and why isn't it working fine now ?

```
anjanMac:eclipse anjanb$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home
anjanMac:eclipse anjanb$
```

I can compile and run java(using jdk 8) just fine on the command line.

So, what's wrong and how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse looks for a JRE to use in various places if not specified in eclipse.ini. Try specifying the 1.8 JDK/JRE in eclipse.ini, something like this in your case: (note the separate lines)

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

More info on the detailed setup here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini ("-vm value: Mac OS X Example")

Comment: I tried this however I still get the same error message.

Comment: A similar problem still exists for Eclipse Photon and High Sierra in 2018. You need to download JAVA SDK from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html and edit eclipse.ini as described.

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse doesn't recognize that java is updated with the standard java updater. What worked for me was installing the Java SE Development kit 8.

Download from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). Try to open the installer again after installing the SE.